# Magnetic susceptibility error by binning Monte Carlo

Tags: simulations, error-analysis, ising-model

I am studying the 2D Ising model using Monte Carlo simulations and I have learned the binning (or batching) method for the error statistical analysis. Following this discussion https://books.google.it/books?id=3HIZDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=montecarlo+method+blocking&source=bl&ots=uGuCoCV02v&sig=ACfU3U1j1IvDhJ9vVhuG9eUfKI0IIWe4Fw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr8t6Fs5bhAhVNsaQKHYPGClgQ6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=montecarlo%20method%20blocking&f=false (page 50) I have understood that the error of an observable $X$ is computed through the error of the block averages as
$$\text{var}(\overline{X})=\frac{1}{N_{blocks}}\text{var}(\overline{X}_{blocks})$$
Now my problem is the following: if the observable I am interested in is the magnetic susceptibility, which is computed from the magnetisation data as $\chi=\beta\text{var}(m)$, where $m$ is the magnetisation and $\beta$ is the inverse temperature, after having divided the Monte Carlo data into sub-blocks and having found uncorrelated block averages, how do I find the error associated to $\chi$? It seems to be the variance of the variance, but it is non-sense for me.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If every collection of $N_\text{blocks}$ generate one value of $\chi$, then you can repeat the experiment $M$ times to estimate $\chi$ as
$$ \overline{\chi}\approx \chi_M=\frac{1}{M}\sum^M_{i=1}\chi^{(i)}.$$
Where $\chi^{(i)}$ is the result of the $i^{th}$ measure. This procedure involves generating $N_\text{blocks}\times M$ samples.

Therefore, $\chi_M$ is a random variable itself. The errors of the estimation of $\overline{\chi}$ with $\chi_M$ scale with the standard error,
$$\text{err}_M=\sqrt{\frac{\text{var}(\chi)}{M}},$$
which can be estimated using one more time a sample mean
$$\text{var}(\chi)\approx\text{var}_M(\chi)=\frac{1}{M}\sum^M_{i=1}(\chi^{(i)})^2-\chi_M^2.$$

Answer (score -1):

Fear not! I think it is possible to take the variance of the variance of the variance.

Comment: But in order to compute the variance you need a set of measures, while here I would have just $\chi$ (which is a variance). So how to compute its variance?